# my phone galaxy s4 is not discovered by Tizen wearable IDE

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I want to develop and test Gear 2 Tizen apps on my Galaxy S4. But the device is not discovered by Tizen wearable IDE. I have Mac 10.9.3.

I need device DUID to be able to test apps on it but device is not discovered in "connection explorer".

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I enabled development mode in the watch and connected it to my PC.  Samsung documentation was unclear and didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

You mean S4 is not detected by Tizen SDK? It's not supposed to be.
But the SDK should detect the Gear device.

Comment: Yes I mean that. To test my apps, Samsung needs device DUID and help says that I should connect my mobile to computer and open Tizen IDE and so I can see device DUID. I followed instructions but nothing appeared. I also connected real gear2 via usb and nothing appeared also.

the only thing that succeeded is the Gear 2 emulator. So I can test Gear2 standalone apps only. But my application is integrated app which has an app on Android side so I cant test it.

anyone succeeded in that on Mac?

Comment: Where does it say that you should connect your mobile? As I understand it, you should need only DUID of the Gear2 device.
If you connect the Gear2 device and nothing happens, check the Gear2 settings (I think there is developer mode there which should be enabled).

And if you're only testing perhaps you don't need to integrate the apps.

Comment: Did you try these steps on a real Gear2 device ?

Comment: I think you are confused. The guide says to connect your Gear to your computer, then open the Tizen IDE and right-click it to get the DUID from the properties. Then generate a certificate with the DUID, encrypt it and send it to Samsung to sign. Then import the returned certificate as a security profile, THEN you can test your app on your Gear. It has nothing to do with your android phone (as far as certificates and DUID's go)